# Get the ids of the previously executed states in spring web flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

In my Spring Webflow application, I am trying to show the list of ids of executed states (from start) (view-state and action-state) at a current point. So, is there a method in Java, which I can use to get this information?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest setting up and using a `FlowExecutionListener`, specifically the methods `sessionStarted`, `stateEntered` and `sessionEnded`

you can get the id of a state using `context.getCurrentState().getId()`

```
public class MyFlowListener implements FlowExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void stateEntered(RequestContext context, StateDefinition previousState, StateDefinition state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionStarted(RequestContext context, FlowSession session) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionEnded(RequestContext context, FlowSession session, String outcome, AttributeMap<?> output) {

    }
}
```

you can register your listener like this (xml config):

```
<bean id="myFlowListener" class="my.custom.webflow.MyFlowExecutionListener"/>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">  
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>  
        <webflow:listener ref="myFlowListener"/>  
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>  
</webflow:flow-executor>
```